# UITextField textColor updates in iOS10, not in iOS 11

Tags: ios, uitextfield, textcolor

My code fragment is very small:

```
self.textField.textColor = color
```

This is called in response to user interaction. It has been working for years. On my iOS 10 device it still works. On my iOS 11 device, the color does not change until I tap in the text field.

Bug? Feature? Workaround? Suggestions welcome.

Comment: Provide more context. Show the whole method this line is in.

Comment: Did you set a break point at this line with iOS 11? Make sure this called.

Comment: I did show the whole method. The method is being called. At the risk of repeating myself, the exact same code works on iOS 10 (and has worked on 9, 8, & 7) but fails on iOS 11.

Comment: Looping back in here, looks like this works as intended in iOS 12 (similarly to 10 and older). This seems like a bug in iOS 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can trigger the text color change to take effect by adding this line below the single line cited above:

```
self.textField.text = self.textField.text
```

However, given the facts above, it still looks to me like a bug outside of my code. Or, at least, a change of the implicit class contract.

Answer (score 7):

You might need to update/reset your UITextField text right after the color change:

```
self.textField.textColor = color
self.textField.text = "Hi! I've changed of color!!"
```

Andrew update, more practical stuff:

```
 self.textField.textColor = color
 self.textField.text =  self.textField.text
```

Comment: In fact, adding the line self.textField.text = self.textField.text does fix the problem. Why didn't I think of that? The mystery remains, and from the symptoms I really do suspect it's a new bug/feature in the OS.